# Image not appearing in Ttkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

What I'm trying to do is to display the image cover from a flac file like in the pic below (this one is hard coded).

[image: Text]

I ripped the cover with the function `getCoverFlac` from my code, but the problem begins when I try to update this img with my `imgSet` fucntion, the image to load exist(can see it in the dir and can even be used hard coded), but the image wont appear in the Ttkinter window. I believe its receiving the right file name since it returns the name correctly:

```
name of cover to display:Shikao Suga - Yuudachi ('99 NHK Hall 0 Live).flacCover.jpg
```

[image: Text]

so how can I fix this?
full code bellow:

```
import pygame
import tkinter as tkr
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import *
import os
from mutagen.flac import FLAC, Picture
import os.path
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

music_player = tkr.Tk()
cont = 0
music_player.title("My Music Player")
music_player.geometry("600x600")
play_list = tkr.Listbox(music_player, font="Helvetica 12 bold", bg='yellow', selectmode=tkr.SINGLE)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

def play():
    pygame.mixer.music.load(play_list.get(tkr.ACTIVE))
    #gets  and set the var name
    var.set(play_list.get(tkr.ACTIVE))
    #gets the cover and sets the the img that will be in panel
    getThecover = getCoverFlac(play_list.get(tkr.ACTIVE))
    imgSet(getThecover)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    
def stop():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
def pause():
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
def unpause():
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
def selectDir():
    directory = askdirectory()
    os.chdir(directory)
    song_list = os.listdir()
    for item in song_list:
        pos = 0
        play_list.insert(pos, item)
        pos += 1

def  getCoverFlac(flac_file):
#this fucntion extracts the image from the flac file and saves it in the dir where the flac file is.
        flacObj = FLAC(flac_file)
        coverArt = flacObj.pictures
        coverName = str(flac_file)+"Cover.jpg"
        if os.path.isfile(coverName):
            print(coverName+" already exists")
        else:
            for img in coverArt:
                if img.type == 3:
                    with open(coverName, "wb") as f:
                        f.write(img.data)
                    print(coverName+" created and saved")
                    #img.show()
        return coverName
    
def imgSet(var):
#sets the global var "img" to var
    global img
    print("name of cover to display:"+var)
    resizeImg(var)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(var))

def resizeImg(imgName):
    basewidth = 300
    img = Image.open(imgName)
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(imgName)

Button1 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="PLAY", command=play, bg="blue", fg="white")
Button2 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="STOP", command=stop, bg="red", fg="white")
Button3 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="PAUSE", command=pause, bg="purple", fg="white")
Button4 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="UNPAUSE", command=unpause, bg="orange", fg="white")
Button5 = tkr.Button(music_player, width=5, height=3, font="Helvetica 12 bold", text="Music Dir", command=selectDir, bg="green", fg="white")



var = tkr.StringVar() 


song_title = tkr.Label(music_player, font="Helvetica 12 bold", textvariable=var)
resizeImg('Haddaway - What Is Love (70 Mix).flacCover.jpg')
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Haddaway - What Is Love (70 Mix).flacCover.jpg'))

    
panel = tkr.Label(music_player, image = img, justify=CENTER)

song_title.pack()
panel.pack(fill="x")
Button1.pack(fill="x")
Button2.pack(fill="x")
Button3.pack(fill="x")
Button4.pack(fill="x")
Button5.pack(fill="x")
play_list.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
music_player.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just update the global variable `img` inside `imageSet()`, but forget to update the image of the label using `panel.config(image=img)`:

```py
def imgSet(var):
#sets the global var "img" to var
    global img
    print("name of cover to display:"+var)
    resizeImg(var)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(var))
    panel.config(image=img) # update image of label "panel"
```